While using the declaretheoremstyle command, what is the argument for the body to be Roman font?
I am using the thmtools package to declare a theorem style.
I want to declare a theorem style with body font the Roman font (like the body font in \theoremstyle{definition}).
I have read that the argument for bodyfont should be a TeX command.
Is the rmfamily the correct argument?
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
bodyfont=\normalfont\rmfamily, % I am not sure if I should write "rmfamily" here.
]{newstyle}

\declaretheorem[
style=newstyle,
name=Theorem,
]{theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
    This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
    
\end{document}

By the way, I have searched that the code for italics is \itshape and the code for bold font is \bfseries. Where can I find a complete list for argument corresponding to different fonts (like the typewriter font, sans serif font) for the headfont and bodyfont in \declaretheoremstyle command?

\rmfamily isn't necessary. You find the font selection declarations in any LaTeX manual.

Thanks. Simply put bodyfont=\normalfont indeed works.

As mentioned in the comments, \normalfont works.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
%headfont=\normalfont\bfseries, % this is the default
bodyfont=\normalfont,
]{newstyle}

\declaretheorem[
style=newstyle,
name=Theorem,
]{theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
    This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
    
\end{document}


To answer your second question, you can find a list of all font commands in fntguide.
